# WordPress Add advertising ads befor and after content with periority

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, filters, the-content

How we can use function with filter to add ads before and after content,
Every ad has its priority.
How we can use parameters at function then use it at filter
This is the function

```
    function mywp_before_after($content) {
    if(is_page() || is_single()) {
        $beforecontent = 'This goes before the content. Isn\'t that awesome!';
        $aftercontent = 'And this will come after, so that you can remind them of something, like following you on Facebook for instance.';
        $fullcontent = $beforecontent . $content . $aftercontent;
    } else {
        $fullcontent = $content;
    }

    return $fullcontent;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'mywp_before_after');
```

Needed

```
function mywp_before_after($content,$place,$priority) {
if ($place =='before'):
 $fullcontent = $beforecontent . $content;
else:
 $fullcontent =$content . $aftercontent;

}
 add_filter('the_content', 'mywp_before_after',10,2,$place,$priority);
```

Comment: asking people to do work for you is not very polite. please edit your question so it will not sound like your are looking for someone  to develop code for you for free. In addition it is not actually clear what is it that you want, what priority, what should be its impact etc.

Comment: @MarkKaplun , Your reply is not very polite. We ask for how we can use parameters of function in add_filter. We didn't request to do work for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use add_filter() for each advertisement so you can set the priority accordingly. Example:

```
// Ad 1
function myprefix_ad_1( $content ) {
    $ad = 'Your ad code';
    return $ad_1 . $content; // this one is before
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'myprefix_ad_1', 10 );

// Ad 2
function myprefix_ad_2( $content ) {
    $ad = 'Your ad code';
    return $content . $ad; // This one is after
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'myprefix_ad_2', 20 );
```

Comment: Great! If you have a look at my second suggestion it is much more dynamic though and easier to maintain/update - you could even hook it into a custom post type to manage your adds via custom posts ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually here is a more advanced method you can use by storing your ads in a loop and looping through them to add your filters. It's pretty cool stuff ;)

```
function myprefix_ads() {
    return array(
        'ad-1' => array(
            'priority'  => 10,
            'content'   => 'Ad for pages before',
            'placement' => 'before',
            'condition' => 'is_page'
        ),
        'ad-2' => array(
            'priority'  => 10,
            'content'   => 'Add for posts after',
            'placement' => 'after',
            'condition' => 'is_single'
        )
    );
}

$ads = myprefix_ads();

foreach ( $ads as $key => $val ) {

    add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) use ( $val ) {

        if ( isset( $val['condition'] ) && ! call_user_func( $val['condition'] ) ) {
            return $content;
        }

        if ( 'before' == $val['placement'] ) {

            $content = $val['content'] . $content;

        } elseif ( 'after' == $val['placement'] ) {

            $content = $content . $val['content'];

        }

        return $content;

    }, $val['priority'] );

}
```